# Is an NHL defender credited with a block if the puck still enters the goal?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, nhl, own-goal

If the puck hits a defender, but the puck proceeds to enter the goal they are defending anyway, is that defender still credited with a block (against that shot)?

Comment: I suspect this is up to the scorer, but not sure. May also depend on if it goes directly in vs. if it deflects off another person. Do you mean they get a piece of it but it just goes in, or they block it and then it goes off another person (stick or otherwise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a goal requires counting a shot on goal to the attacker, but a blocked shot is (by definition) not able to be a shot on goal, which makes them exclusionary.

That would mean a shot attempt that leads to a goal cannot also be counted as a blocked shot. Put simply: either it is a goal or it is blocked, never both.

The NHL doesn't say anything formal on the matter that I can find, so this might be a case of "ask whoever you're getting stats from".

Answer (score 1):

This question begs another one: *Credited by who?*

Every single sports statistics service probably have their own definition for such stuff.

For example, in one football app a ball that came back from the post or the bar is accepted as a "shot on target" while in another app it is not.

Again, for some people a pass is an assist if only it is converted by the first touch after the pass and not if the receiver starts dribbling after receiving it.

The examples were from football. For your question, by logic, if a ball is **blocked** it shouldn't make it to the goal. So he shouldn't be credited. However, statistics are a gray area case and answer usually changes based on who you ask.