# Are own goals considered when calculating goal conversion rate?

Tags: football, statistics, scoring, own-goal

In football, goal conversion rate is calculated as the number of goals scored divided by the number of shots taken.

Suppose the opposition scores an own goal in a game, or several such goals across a competition. Are the own goal(s) included when calculating a team's goal conversion rate?

Comment: I would highly doubt it.

Comment: Compare [this question about NHL](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/15229#15229). It can't be both a missed shot and a goal, so with that logic, it can't be both an own goal and count towards the goals scored by the team (which is also somewhat the definition). I don't have a football-specific source on this at the moment though.

Comment: I have no source, but it's pretty much impossible to count them in. The conversion rates are usually calculated per player and then summed up. It would be inconsistent to add them to the game's rate and leave the player's rates alone.

Answer (score -1):

@Monish Koyyot is actually right about conclusion, but his reasoning is false. First thing you need to be aware of: FIFA, nor UEFA for that matter, keep, show or in any way calculate shot percentage(conversion rate) stats - they're not standard in football statistics. Major Football leagues, like Premier, Primera, Bundesliga, Calcio, do often provide more in-depth player stats, but there's no written standar on how's this done.

Another thing, you'll need to understand is what an shot percentage actually is, as in, **which stats go into account**. So, conversion rate, or shot percentage, in football, is represented as **successfulness in scoring a goal against opposition team**, not really as one's general contribution to the game. I know that may not seam right, but that's how all major football leagues define it.

Shot percentage is calculated by dividing a total number of shots with total goals scored. Note that if one player is responsible for an own goal, or auto-goal, he/she did not really score. I know it's common phrasing to say that he/she scored own goal, but in football terminology, that doesn't really account for scoring a goal.

That being said, in none of the major Football leagues own goals go into shot percentage calculation. Penalties are, on the other hand, often calculated as 85% of the in game goal score.

Comment: Any comment as to why vote down?

Answer (score -2):

Own goals scored are reflected in the score sheet and therefore included in the total goals scored by the team at the end of the season. So, logically speaking they do include it the goal conversion rate for the team and not for any individual.

Comment: This isn't entirely valid reasoning. Goal conversion rate could easily be calculated without own goals if it were defined that way; assuming that the total goals scored must be worked out from final scorelines alone and not from actual scoresheets or databases that allow the difference to be noted, isn't good enough to support this response for an answer.